# Displaying and deleting lat/long points (from CSV file) on map

Tags: maps, csv

I am looking for a piece of software that will

1. easily let me display lat long points from a CSV file on a map,
2. then be able to select a group of points (via a box or drawing),
3. delete the points and resave as a CSV.

ArcGIS requires way too many steps to do this over and over again, Power map in Excel shows the points but can't be edited, Tableaux shows the points on a map, allows me to filter the bad points out but have not found a way to then resave the filtered data to a new CSV.

Comment: Do you have to do this "over and over again" with the same layer (re-modifications over time) or is this for different layers?